# Please help me solve this probem on polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, contest-math

> Let
>
> $$f(x)=a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+a_2 x^{n-2}+\cdots+a_n $$
>
> be a polynomial of degree $n$ with real coefficients and $a_1^2<a_2$.
>   Show that not all roots of $f(x)$ can be real.

Please help me solve this problem in a simple way as I am only a high school student.

[(image of problem)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mK1pb.jpg)

Comment: Please use mathjax.

Comment: @ Wuestenfux Please check it now I have added an image.

Comment: Please don't use pictures.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde Sorry for the inconvenience, but I do not know  how to use mathjax

Comment: Then start reading [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Dietrich Burde Please help now !!

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks a lot for helping

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Stop bullying the kid..

Comment: @JingeonAn Two courteous requests and a standard response to such questions like this one (WHYDSF) does not even come close to bullying, so let’s try to ramp down the tone a bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a proof when $a_0=1$.

If all the roots are real, call them $b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n$ (not necessarily distinct.)  Then $$
f(x)=(x-b_1)(x-b_2)\cdots(x-b_n)$$
We have $$
a_1=-\sum_{i=1}^nb_i\\
a_2=\sum_{i<j}b_ib_j$$
So the condition is $$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^nb_i\right)^2<\sum_{i<j}b_ib_j\\
\sum_{i=1}^nb_i^2+2\sum_{i<j}b_ib_j<\sum_{i<j}b_ib_j
$$
$$
\sum_{i=1}^nb_i^2+\sum_{i<j}b_ib_j<0\tag1
$$
Since all the $b_i$ are real, we see from $(1)$ that$$
\sum_{i<j}b_ib_j<0\tag2$$ Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ gives $$
\sum_{i=1}^nb_i^2+2\sum_{i<j}b_ib_j<0\\
\left(\sum_{i=1}^nb_i\right)^2<0$$
contradiction.

**EDIT**

The statement is not true for general $a_0$.  Consider $$\frac{x^2}{100}-\frac x{50}+\frac1{100}=\frac{(x-1)^2}{100}$$
We have $a_1=-\frac1{50},\ a_2=\frac1{100}$ so that the condition holds and all the roots are real.

Comment: You are right. I should have check more.

Comment: That's okay.  I've made that same mistake many times.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call the roots (real or complex) of the polynomial as $r_i$. Then the polynomial can be written as
$$f(x)=a_0(x-r_1)(x-r_2)(x-r_3)...(x-r_n)$$

Developing it a bit we get:
$$f(x) = a_0x^n -(r_1+r_2+r_3+...+r_n)x^{n-1} + 2(r_1 r_2 + r_1 r_3 +...+r_2r_3+r_2r_4+... )x^{n-2} +... $$
Where you can see that $a_1=-(r_1+r_2+r_3+...+r_n)$ and $a_2=2(pairs\;summatory)$

Now, calculate $a_1^2$
$$a_1^2= r_1^2+r_2^2+...+r_n^2 \;+\; 2(r_1 r_2 + r_1 r_3 +...+r_2r_3+r_2r_4+... )$$

If $a_1^2 < a_2$ then we have
$$r_1^2+r_2^2+...+r_n^2 \;+\; 2(r_1 r_2 + r_1 r_3 +...+r_2r_3+r_2r_4+... ) < 2(r_1 r_2 + r_1 r_3 +...+r_2r_3+r_2r_4+... )$$

Which results in $$r_1^2+r_2^2+...+r_n^2 < 0$$

Because squares are always $>=0$ for real numbers the result above ($<0$) is only possible with complex numbers.
That means at at least one of $r_i$ is complex, not all roots are real.